# Creating URL slugs for tags with acts-as-taggable-on using friendly_id

Tags: url, ruby-on-rails-3.1, slug, acts-as-taggable-on, friendly-id

I'm trying to follow the answer on this question in order to create url friendly slugs for tags:

[Creating url slugs for tags with acts_as_taggable_on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982589/creating-url-slugs-for-tags-with-acts-as-taggable-on/5990274#5990274)

In initalizers I have:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `slug' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: nil, name: "test listing">
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That post is using the old gem, where as you're using FriendlyId 4.x which requires a `slug` column of type string on your Tag model. .. I will post some code shortly (currently commuting to work)

Answer (score 0):

Using what I read in the referenced post, I have a potential solution

run `rails g migration AddSlugToTags slug:string`

this should generate the following migration:

```
class AddSlugToTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tags, :slug, :string
  end
end
```

of course, run `rake db:migrate` to set that up.

Then your initializer code above should work.

**Note:** I haven't tried this myself but it makes sense that it would work.

Hope this helps.