# Ruby On Rails: friendly_id on acts_as_taggable_on, updating slug column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, friendly-id

I think I have it setup properly per these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982589/creating-url-slugs-for-tags-with-acts-as-taggable-on/5990274#5990274)

But when I'm trying to update the slug column in an existing app like so for my tags:

```
Tag.find_each(&:save)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Tag
```

Is `Tag` not the correct one?

---

EDIT: FULL ERROR LOG

```
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags"  ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `slugged' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x007faafaefc458>
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/friendly_id-5.1.0/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:295:in `should_generate_new_friendly_id?'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/friendly_id-5.1.0/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:304:in `set_slug'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in `valid?'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in `valid?'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:83:in `perform_validations'
... 20 levels...
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/hellomello/sites/project_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/hellomello/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.1 :042 >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Tag
```

It means that `Tag` class was not loaded in the environment.

Try to use the name scoped name like: `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` (like the link you posted) rather than `Tag` only. Also, see if you need to `require` the `act_as_taggable_on.rb` file somewhere so that it loads properly. This error happens when the class doesn't load properly.

Did you add the new class to the `/lib/` directory? Then, check (or add) if you have something like this in your `application.rb` file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: I'm getting close. I did `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_each(&:save)` but returning this error now: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'slugged' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x007faaf6472248>`. And I added the file named `acts_as_taggable_on.rb` to my `/initializers/` folder. And I don't know what the autoload_paths do

Comment: can you paste the full error log in your question section?

Comment: I think, you need to use: `Model.friendly.find` rather than `Model.find`

Comment: what's your `friendly_id` gem version?

Comment: Hello, I updated to show error. The error is coming from doing the find_each(&:save) when I'm trying to update my slug column

Comment: Try: `Model.friendly.find_each` insted. see if that works

Comment: I believe its the most up to date. I didn't set a version in my gem file. 5.1.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87436/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-hellomello).

Comment: @hellomello is there any update on this? I was waiting for your github repo! Let me know!

Comment: oh!! hello! sorry, dang. Been really busy. I was trying to work on it myself for awhile. I'm going to try to work on it this weekend. If you don't mind, I'll email you when its finally up! Sorry!! No need to wait on me!

Comment: No problem, just shoot me an email when the project is up on github and give me collaboration access.