# Rails 4: parameterize acts_as_taggable_on urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using acts_as_taggable_on for my tagging system, wherein each article has one or more tags. However, the way it's setup now, the tags are capitalized and have spaces as well as special characters between them and these carry through to my routes. In other words, a tag like "Barack Obama" passes all the way to the routes unchanged; it seems my urls are completely unencoded.

I'm wondering what the correct way to deal with this is.

My articles controller looks like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_articles, only: [:tagged]

  def tagged
    @tag = params[:tag]
    tagged_with = @articles.tagged_with(@tag)
    if @tag.present? && tagged_with.present?
      @articles = tagged_with
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "Oops! There are no articles with tagged #{@tag}"
    end
  end

  private
  def set_articles
    @articles = user_signed_in? ? Article.all : Article.where published: true
  end
end
```

and my routes.rb look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  # This is the route that generates publicly facing tag urls:
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#tagged', as: :tag, tag: /.*/
  # This is for internal use:
  %w(people cities countries other).each do |tag|
    get tag, to: "articles#collect_tags", as: tag, tag: tag
  end
end
```

When I click a tag, my urls currently look like:

`http://mywebsite.com/tags/Barack Obama`

or

`http://mywebsite.com/tags/Shinzō Abe`

I'm not sure if these are being internally escaped or if something needs doing? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I handle urls for tags tags using friendly_id - which automatically handles searching by name or id, you just have to provide the slug field.

First, install friendly_id

> https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Create a migration to add a slug to your tag

```
#db/migrate/123123123123123_add_slug_to_tag.rb
class AddSlugToTag < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tags, :slug, :string
    add_index :tags, :slug
  end
end
```

Add an initializer for acts_as_taggable_on that sets up a slug.

```
#config/initializers/friendly_acts_as_taggable.rb
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name,
  use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

Then in your controller, find the tag first, then search against your object list

```
 #articles_controller.rb
 @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.friendly.find(params[:tag])
 tagged_with = @articles.tagged_with(@tag)
```

---

To do this without friendly id

You still need all the components above, but things change.

Your initializer would look something like:

```
# This is so we can have slugs for tag urls
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  before_create :add_slug
  def add_slug
    self.slug = self.name.parameterize
  end
end
```

And the query in your controller should instead be

```
@tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where(slug: params[:tag]).first
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do this without relying on another Gem that you're aware of?

Comment: Also, I think the `before_create :add_slug` part should actually be `before_save :add_slug` with a check in the add_slug method to make sure the tag hasn't changed. The above solution will only work when a tag is first created and will ignore any future tag modifications.

Answer (score 0):

So there appears to be [a simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973373/1741325) that doesn't require any additional gems.

However, upon further investigation, I can see that the tags are generating urls with %20 instead of spaces, so I believe acts_as_taggable_on generates safe urls by default (but don't quote me on this!)

Comment: What solution did you end up using?  Did you just leave the generated urls with %20?  I see your post to valachi's answer but I don't understand the if statement.

Comment: I just left it as is. I don't think it causes any security risk.