# Rails: Friendly_id on tags with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, friendly-id

I am on rails 4, and I am trying to use slug to make my tags url prettier.

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982589/creating-url-slugs-for-tags-with-acts-as-taggable-on/5990274#5990274). But it doesn't work. Here is my code.

I generated a slug for my tags column.

```
class AddSlugTotaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tags, :slug, :string
    add_index :tags, :slug
  end
end
```

And I created an initializers:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  extend FriendlyId

  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

But when I am inspecting my tags in console, the slug column is nil.

For example, from the command line:

Tag.find(1) return:

```
SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Tag id: 1, name: "testtag", taggings_count: 1, slug: nil>
```

Edit:

Here is my controller: tags_controller.rb

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag =  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id])
    @pins = Pin.tagged_with(@tag.name)
  end

end
```

When I access the url /tags/1 it works well. But if I try to access /tags/startup it does not work here is the error:

```
Couldn't find ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag with 'id'=startup
```

Answer (score 2):

The current version of FriendlyId no longer overrides finders by default.

Instead you would use:

```
Tag.friendly_find(1)
```

If you really need the FriendlyId 4 style finders than you would can add the finders addon:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```